# Integrated API manager + twitter account

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have integrated wso2 api manager(store) 2.0.0 with Twitter. Authentication is successful but i can't able to display the twitter username on api manager store.
could you please help me any one.

Thanks,

Raju K

Comment: Have you tried configuring the claim mapping ? e.g for facebook  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Logging+into+the+Identity+Server+using+Facebook+Credentials#LoggingintotheIdentityServerusingFacebookCredentials-ConfiguringclaimmappingsforFacebook

Comment: Yes, i had tried with claim option also but not working.